# Change all Administrators wallpaper

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I want to change all admin's wallpaper to one I define (changing the registry value is enough for what I want to do).

What I thought is get all profiles and search all admins into it:

```
foreach (var sid in Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList")
    .GetSubKeyNames().Select(profile => new SecurityIdentifier(profile)))
{
    if (sid.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.AccountAdministratorSid)
        || sid.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid))
    {
        // Is admin
    }
}
```

It works fine, except that the SID stored in `HKEY_USERS` doesn't fit with the Admins SID I get ahead.

How can I get the matching `HKEY_USERS` SID from my Admin one?

IE. for an Admin profile:

- In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` : SID is `S-1-5-21-A-B-C-500`
- In `HKEY_USERS` it is : `S-1-5-21-A-B-C-D` (where A-B-C fits, but where comes D from?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the following workaround:

```
string adminKey = Registry.Users.GetSubKeyNames()
                    .FirstOrDefault(key => key.StartsWith(sid.AccountDomainSid.Value) && char.IsDigit(key[key.Length - 1]));

if (adminKey != null) // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding users in the registry and checking if they are in 'Administrators', you can do it by enumerating all users in the 'Administrators' group with an LDAP query.

```
using (DirectoryEntry groupEntry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://./Administrators,group"))
{
  foreach (object member in (IEnumerable)groupEntry.Invoke("Members"))
  {
    using (DirectoryEntry memberEntry = new DirectoryEntry(member))
    {
      Console.WriteLine(memberEntry.Path);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't give me the Registry path of the Admins in order to access to the `Wallpaper` key.

Comment: you can retrieve your SID and so find your registry path with somthing like that :SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier((byte[])memberEntry.Properties["objectSid"].Value, 0);

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, isn't the way to get an admin SID the problem, but doing the correspondance with `HKEY_USERS`

Comment: if the problem is finding admins in HKEY_USERS any user starting with S-1-5-21 has local admin privileges you just have to enumerate the keys, I don't see the point in matching them with the profiles in HKLM